# Looking for a SQL Server system-wide search solution

Tags: sql, sql-server, search, full-text-search

I'm trying to create a solution to allow my users to perform a google-like search of records in my database. By this, I mean they can search for data in a variety of ways without specifying a column. Here are a few points to understand my structure and specs.

- The user should be able to search for any keyword
- The data will come from multiple tables through inner joins
- The data is constantly changing and search results must be real-time

Here's how I'm accomplishing this today:

Every time a record, or corresponding record, changes we create a record in our searchindex table with all of the related keywords associated with that record. For example, an inventory record would have the receipt number, order number, inventory status etc all coming for joined tables. The searchindex table is indexed with SQL Server full text indexing and it works pretty well.

The problem:

The issue with the current setup is that we have to maintain the data in the searchindex table. Which means that every time in our code when any of the data changes, we need to call a stored procedure to update the searchindex. Because of the complexity of our application, this is too cumbersome and fails too often.

I want to implement a more fluid solution so that the searchindex is constantly up-to-date.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: There is absolutely no way you would be happy with this type of search. You are basically asking if there is a way to search through every single column of every single table to find a specific value, and you want it fast. This is like asking somebody to find all the occurrences of the name "steve" in all phone books for the state of california. It can be done but it isn't going to be fast.

Comment: I'd suggest keeping your current solution, and updating your searchindex table once a day in off-peak hours.

Comment: @SeanLange I'm not asking for every column to be searchable. Only a few, but they are in different tables

Comment: Have a scheduled process update a separate table like Tab said.  I know you said "real-time" is a requirement, but that cannot be done practically.  You have to choose between real-time or real-fast.

Comment: To do the updates during peak hours, you could look into a partition-switching solution.

Comment: Perhaps a happy medium of real-time and real-fast is possible. You could keep your existing process running which sounds like it captures most of the data. Then do a nightly re-indexing process to get everything corrected.

Comment: @StanShaw Truth is, time is not really a concern of mine. It's more important to be real-time. However, I don't want to union a bunch of tables together to search each column.

Comment: I would use triggers to manage the changes. If searchIndex management processing time is too demanding i would just queue the changes and trickle the searchIndex updates. Index would be maintained in "near" real-time.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a view to eliminate the need for the single table that has to be updated constantly. Something like:

```
CREATE VIEW Full_Search
AS
    SELECT invoice_number AS search_text, 'Invoices' AS table_name, 'invoice_number' AS column_name, invoice_id AS id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT part_number AS search_text, 'Parts' AS table_name, 'part_number' AS column_name, part_id AS id
    ...
```

You can then search against the view to find the table, column, and rows where there is a match. This relies on all of your tables having a PK that is a single column so that they can be mixed together.

Performance will depend greatly on how the searches are done. If the searches allow for the use of indexes (for example, no `WHERE search_text LIKE '%value%'`) then performance might not be that bad.